# Escaping javascript onclick with json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've got a button I build with php to fire a javascript onclick event:

```
<button onClick='edit(this, "<?php echo $this->result[$i]["type"]; ?>","<?php echo $quality; ?>", "<?php echo json_encode($stuff); ?>", ...)">
</button>
```

I just added the json data `$stuff`. Now when I'm in javascript to get some values:

```
jQuery(stuff).each(function(index) {
            console.log( "The key is " + this.name + " and the value is " + this.hash );
    });
```

I get this error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

This is because json data is using double quotes so the result looks something like this:

`"foo", "bar", "[{"name":"test","hash":"123"},{"name":"test1","hash":"456"},..."`

In this onclick event I've tried changing the quotes to single quotes or vice versa. I've tried escaping quotes with backslashes. It seems nothing works. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data)` on the client side and `json_encode(data)` on the server.

Comment: @localghost tried that as well with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the quotes for the json that you are returning? You can do so like this: 
`echo json_encode($this->result[$i]["type"]);`.

It will make your json like this: 
`\"foo\", \"bar\", \"[{\"name\":\"test\",\"hash\":\"123\"}...`.

If your code is already in json, json_encode() shouldn't change anything except adding the blackslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
... "<?php str_replace('"', '\"', $this->result[$i]["type"]); ?> ...
```

Maybe it's because in text you show (type) is **"** character.